# Azure python sdk - getting information of Automation account

Tags: python, azure

I want to get details of Automation Account in a resource group. I have come across this class azure.mgmt.automation.operations.AutomationAccountOperations . The parameters required are client,config ,serializer and deserializer. I am not sure what these parameters are . Can any one please elaborate with an example.

here is the documentation that i am referring

https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-python/ref/azure.mgmt.automation.operations.html#azure.mgmt.automation.operations.Operations

my sample code is

```
> from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials from
> azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient from
> azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient from
> azure.mgmt.automation.operations.automation_account_operations import
> AutomationAccountOperations
> 
> 
> GROUP_NAME = 'group_name'
> 
> subscription_id = '111111-11111-11111-1111'
> 
> 
> credentials = UserPassCredentials(
>     'user123@xyz.com',
>     'password' )
> 
> 
> automation_client =
> AutomationAccountOperations(credentials,subscription_id)
> 
> def get_automation_details():
>     for item in automation_client.list(GROUP_NAME):
>         print(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my sample code using `azure-mgmt-automation` package in Python 3. It works fine for me.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.automation import AutomationClient

subscription_id = '<your subscription id, like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id='<your client id registered in AAD, like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>',
    secret='<your client secret>',
    tenant='<your tenant id, like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx>'
)

client = AutomationClient(credentials, subscription_id)

# List all automation accounts in the subscription
all = client.automation_account.list()
for item in all:
    print(item)

# List the automation accounts of a resource group
resource_group_name = '<your resource group name>'
accounts_by_rg = client.automation_account.list_by_resource_group(resource_group_name)
for item in accounts_by_rg:
    print(item)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks peter this was very helpful. I want to find out details of machines under update management in this automation account . How can i get that